# use lib relative path not working

Tags: perl, path

I have a perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use lib 'lib';
use SOME_MOD;
```

that works on my old server.
On the new server, it only works with absolute path, like

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use lib '/var/www/apps/myapp/lib';
use SOME_MOD;
```

What do i miss?

Comment: What do you mean by "it only works"? How does it not work with a relative path? Show errors, output (or say output is missing), etc.

Comment: the script is in /var/www/apps/myapp/, lib is in /var/www/apps/myapp/lib/
lib is not in @INC, same on new an old server.

Comment: error_log:  Can't locate MOD_MAIN.pm in @INC

Comment: You do realize that you are `use`ing two different modules in your two examples, right? `SOME_MOD` and `MOD_MAIN`?

Comment: What's your working directory when you launch the script?

Comment: Can you confirm which directory the script is present. And if MOD_MAIN.pm exists in the lib directory?

Comment: That awkward moment when everyone realises the OP may have made a typo, and are waiting for him/her to confirm or deny it, but the OP says nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_perl's cwd is not the same as the scripts location.
Relative path resolution works when Webserver is configured with Perl CGI Script Support.

Answer (score 3):

The directories in `@INC` is always relative the current working directory, but some web servers set the cwd to `/`. If you want a patch relative to the directory in which the script resides, you can use

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib "$RealBin/lib";
```

Alternatively, since the directory you want to add is `$RealBin/lib` or `$RealBin/../lib`, you can use [mylib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?mylib).

```
use mylib;
```

Comment: @ikegami `some web servers set the cwd to /`

Where can i change this?

Comment: could be like this:
mod_perl's cwd not the same as the scripts location.

Comment: mod_perl embeds an Perl interpreter in the Apache process. Yes, the cwd of the Apache+mod_perl process could be `/`.