# lib pragma does not work when script called with relative path

Tags: perl

I have a script `p.pl` in a folder `test`:

```
use lib '.';
use My::Module;
My::Module::my_func();
```

In the test folder there is a subdirectory `My` containing the file `Module.pm`:

```
package My::Module;
sub my_func {
    print "Hello\n";
}    
1;
```

If I run `p.pl` from the test folder by typing `./p.pl` in the terminal window, I get no errors and output `Hello`. If I change directory to the parent (`cd ..`) and type `test/p.pl` I get error:

```
Can't locate My/Module.pm in @INC  at test/p.pl line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test/p.pl line 2.
```

Comment: Found a possible duplicate: [use lib relative path not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096127/use-lib-relative-path-not-working)

Comment: I believe that the current directory is already included in @INC, so `use lib '.';` doesn't mean anything here.

Comment: Adding '.' to lib path is a security weakness like adding '.' to the shell's path.

Comment: @Neil '.' is generally included in the default `@INC`, no need to add it.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Yes you are right, the current directory is included, but it is included at the end of `@INC`. So `use lib '.'` will add it to the front of `@INC`, giving you, for example, a chance to override standard modules by placing your own copy of those in the current directory. For example, this could be used in the case of debugging a CPAN module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [FindBin](https://metacpan.org/pod/FindBin).

`p.pl`:

```
use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::RealBin";
use My::Module;
My::Module::my_func();
```

Comment: Yes, this works.. Maybe the `lib` pragma should not allow use of relative paths? That is: using relative paths with `lib` is never the right thing to do? Or do I miss something?

Comment: I don't have enough overview of the use of lib to give a good answer to that. :) That being said perl does not usually prevent it's users to do a thing just because it's never the right thing to do. :)

Comment: Speaking of never the right thing, use `$RealBin` instead of `$Bin`. This allows people to use symlinks to your script. Adjusted the answer.

Comment: @ikegami: thanks. FindBin uses $FindBin::Bin in the man pages.

Comment: @ikegami Out of curiosity: Is there any reason to use `$FindBin::Bin` over `$FindBin::RealBin`? I guess there should be some use cases; since if not, one could just simplify the API of the `FindBin` module by removing the variable `$FindBin::Bin`..

Comment: @HåkonHægland: One such situation could be where you want to have different libraries depending on which one of the scripts you run. So you link your script to a new directory, and replace the `lib/` with another library to test, or have different functionality.

Comment: @bolav, That's a maintenance nightmare just to avoid copying the script along with the modules. (And it prevents you from linking to the script.)

Comment: @ikegami: Totally agree.

Answer (score 1):

There is no error here.  The use lib pragma adds the directory specified to @INC - the list of directories Perl searches for modules.  By specifying '.', you are saying, "Add the current directory I'm in to @INC", so if you launch the program from the directory above **test**, then that is the folder from which the search is made.