# Perl script can't locate include file when run from the system command

Tags: perl

I have the following files.

```
a.pl

    #!/usr/bin/perl
    system('perl b.pl');

b.pl

    print `cwd`;
    require "conf/cf.pl";

cf.pl

    $var = "val";
    1;
```

And this is the directory set-up.

```
testdir/a.pl
testdir/b.pl
testdir/conf/cf.pl
```

I am in the directory testdir and run the command:

```
perl a.pl
```

This fails with

```
testdir
Can't locate conf/cf.pl in @INC...
```

Why can't it find that include file even though the current directory is correct?

This is on Kali Linux.

Comment: Why is that needed though? It works fine on every other version of linux I've tried.

Comment: Seems like the current directory is missing from your `@INC`. Try add `use lib '.'` in`b.pl` or use `require` with an absolute path name. Note: You can also add the current directory to `@INC` by setting the environment variable `PERL5LIB`.

Comment: @HåkonHægland: Adding `$FindBin::Bin` might be safer, as `cwd` can change.

Comment: @choroba Good point. See also [lib pragma does not work when script called with relative path](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35464832/2173773)

Comment: What's the complete error message?

Comment: I ended up just using the -I flag, I don't know why the current directory isn't included in @INC by default on this installation.

Comment: @user740521 There were some changes very recently because of security issues with the current directory being in `@INC`. Your perl probably includes those changes. This will be standard in 5.26, so you shouldn't rely on `.` being in the default `@INC`.

Comment: I believe there are some distros in the past that omitted `.` from `@INC` too; red hat maybe?

Comment: You [shouldn't](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6376006/589924) be using `require` for `.pl` files; you should be using `do`. (Better solution: Change the `.pl` file into an actual module.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of Perl are you using? There are things afoot to remove the current directory from `@INC` as a response to [CVE-2016-1238](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-1238). Try printing the value of `@INC` in each part of the chain to verify this.

To change this, you can [deliberately add a directory to `@INC`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2526809/2766176).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe command 'cwd' is the problem. Do you have this command in your Linux? I'm assuming you're running this on linux. Anyway, try to change to 'pwd'.